# Change Selection input with jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I've been trying to change a selection input through the use of jquery. When the user clicks on the search field, I would like the selection field to change. Here is the code I'm using to do that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#cat-filter').change( function() {
    var filterText = $(this).val().toLowerCase();       

    if(filterText == 'all events'){
        $('a.events').css("display", "inline");
    } else if(filterText != ''){
        $('a.events:not([categories~="'+ filterText +'"])').css("display", "none");
        $('a.events[categories~="'+ filterText +'"]').css("display", "inline");
    } else {
        $('a.events').css("display", "inline"); 
    }
});
// --------------- THIS IS THE CODE ----------------
$('#search-input').focus( function() {
    $(this).val('');
    $('a.events').css("display", "inline");         
    $("select option:contains(1)").prop('selected', true);
});
//--------------------------------------------------

$('#search-input').blur( function() {
    $(this).val('Search Events');
});


$('#search-input').keyup(function (){
    textField = null;
    var textField = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
    if (textField != ""){
        $('a.events:not([categories*="'+textField+'"])').css("display", "none");
        $('a.events[categories*="'+textField+'"]').css("display", "inline");
    } else {
        $('a.events').css("display", "inline"); 
    }
});





});
```

However it doesn't seem to work. I've checked my id's and values but nothing seems to work. I'm using jquery 1.9, which I've read needs to use prop. Please let me know what I'm doing wrong, thanks!

Here's a live example: http://www.lcbcchurch.com/new-site/events

Answer (score 1):

The issue is not with `.prop` but with the fact that none of your options contain the **1** in their text..

If you want to target the first one (*whose value is 1*) then use

```
$('select option[value="1"]').prop('selected', true);
```

and since you use the uniform plugin you will also have to issue an update so

```
var element = $('select option[value="1"]').prop('selected', true);
$.uniform.update(element.closest('select'));
```